# Библиотеки vector и conio.h вместе не собираются (С++)

Tags: c++, vector

Случайно заметил странную работу компилятора. При отдельном использовании библиотек друг от друга работает всё корректно. Но при совместном использовании библиотек vector и conio.h сборщик выдаёт ошибку. Прошу объяснить с чем это связано. Это баг Visual Studio или моя ошибка?
P.S сам код абсолютно бессмысленный и приведён как пример проблемы.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int>var = {1, 2, 3};
    char flag = 'a';

    while (flag = _getche() != '\r'){
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка в выводе Visual: 1>ConsoleApplication24.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__invalid_parameter в функции "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned(unsigned __int64)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPEAX_K@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication24.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__CrtDbgReport в функции "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned(unsigned __int64)" (??$_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned@U_Default_allocate_traits@std@@@std@@YAPEAX_K@Z).
1>C:\Users\Cain\Desktop\Новая папка\C++\ConsoleApplication24\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication24.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793622/lnk2019unresolved-external-symbol-crtdbgreport-referenced-in-function-crt-rtc

Comment: ¿т.е. если в этом примере закомментировать `#include <conio.h>` и его использование, то он соберется?

Comment: Повторить (VC++ 22 (17.8.4)) не могу, кроме предупреждения о присвоении в пределах условного выражения — ничего. Вы бы ключики компиляции указали...